# Boost build error with websocketpp and MySQL on Windows

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010, boost, websocket

I am trying to build a C++ app that uses both websocketpp and MySQL. I have encountered 2 build problems using VS 2010 C++ Express.

1) A problem with the boost libraries.  It produces many errors like this:

```
 1>c:\program files (x86)\boost\boost_1_50\boost\thread\win32\thread_data.hpp(210): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'rel_time'
```

Here's the relevant snippet from thread_data.hpp starting with line 210:

```
inline BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE void sleep(TimeDuration const& rel_time)
    {
        interruptible_wait(detail::pin_to_zero(rel_time.total_milliseconds()));
    }
```

2) A conflict with the word VERSION which is documented [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/CPP/Q_28005116.html#a38816882) and I believe is independent.

To make a clear and simple example of the boost build problems, I'm using the websocketpp example: [echo_server.cpp](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/examples/echo_server/echo_server.cpp) to which I added these includes:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Boost lib includes recommended by "Building a program with websocketpp" on the websocketpp site.

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp> 
#include <boost/system/api_config.hpp>
#include <boost/system/config.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <boost/system/system_error.hpp>
#include <boost/system/windows_error.hpp>
```

and the MySQL header includes.  Adding these 2 boostincludes triggers the build errors.  If I comment out these 2 includes, it builds without errors:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
```

Any suggestions on how to deal with the boost problems?

I don't think this is the same build problem as this one, "Trying to build websocket++ with MinGW: last few linker errors — what could it be?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the first error, check if there are any macros interfering with the code. Right-click and go to definition or #define the macro yourself at the beginning of the file and see where it gets redefined. In really hard cases, look at the preprocessor output via a compiler flag.

Concerning the rest, you don't provide any versions for Boost and MySQL. Then, there is my_global.h (or is that part of MySQL?) and stdafx.h, which are both under your control but you don't show them here. Also, try to reduce the issue to the smallest possible piece of code. In short, provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you, doomster.  The first problem is indeed a macro.  For more details please see the link in my original message.  In this thread my focus is on the second problem.

stdafx.h is the Microsoft precompiled header file.  I removed it and got the same errors.

my_global.h is part of MySQL, so it's part of the problem.

Versions: Boost: boost_1_50 downloaded 8/3/12.  

MySQL: MySQL Connector C 6.0.2,(downloaded and installed 12/2012) and mysql5.5.16 (about a year old)

So good point--I'll update everything and see if the boost problems persist.

Comment: One clarification:  The VERSION problem is a macro.  doomster, do you think the boost problems are also macro problems?

Comment: TY..."sleep" in \boost_1_51\boost\config\thread_data.hpp 

     `template<typename TimeDuration>
        inline BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE void sleep(TimeDuration const& rel_time)
        {
            interruptible_wait(detail::pin_to_zero(rel_time.total_milliseconds()));
        }`
is being processed as a macro "defined" in ...\mysql\mysql5.5.16\include\my_global.h line 130

    `#define sleep(a) Sleep((a)*1000)`
That explains the error. Is there a way to fix it without editing and rebuilding either boost or MySQL?

Comment: Doomster was correct--both problems were macro conflicts.  The solution was to wrap the MySQL usage using the pImple idiom.